# asyncio tasks (apache beam pipelines) run synchronously in python

Tags: python, python-asyncio, apache-beam

I have the next code:

```
def runner(self):
        logger.info('Start run for parallel jobs...')
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        tasks = []
        for p in self.pipes:
            tasks.append(loop.create_task(catch_async_exceptions(
                self._start_runner(p)
            )))
        loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
        loop.close()

    async def _start_runner(self, pipe):
        result = pipe.run()
        result.wait_until_finish()
        logger.info(f'Runner finished with success. Exit')
```

This code:

```
result = pipe.launch()
result.wait_until_finish()
```

is a long task and in this part program waits for the pipe to complete. I have couple of pipes and I want to run them in parallel. But with this code asyncio still launches the pipes one after another, waits till one finishes and start another. Can I still run them in parallel and make it 'wait_until_finish' in own 'task' to be able to catch exceptions and do not freeze other tasks? Or with asyncio I dont need to wait for pipeline to be completed? Here pipes are **apache beam** pipelines.

Comment: Is the `wait_until_finish` async?

Comment: Unfortunately your `_start_runner` function doesn't **await** anything, so it is async in name only. You need to switch to a pipeline library that actually supports asyncio.